# boto s3 connection - what port used?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

forgive that question but I am a beginner...
I followed some tutorial for creating a python script putting a file onto s3. However, I think my companies firewall is blocking that connection...what port is boto s3 connection using? it is 443, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boto uses port 443 to connect to AWS services.

Comment: is this true?  I've been having an issue where when attempting to connect to AWS via a Boto3 script in lambda with port 443 open it's timing out, and as soon as I open up the the sgit works again...

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 services are accessed over port 443.

I doubt if port 443 is blocked by hour company's firewall. If that is true, I guess you wont be able to access half of the internet.

Check with hour IT team if specific domain names are blocked or rather allowed.